# Why does using a queue data structure in implementing Depth First Search makes it a Breadth First Search?

Tags: data-structures, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, tree-traversal

I know Depth-first search is implemented using a LIFO data structure and using a FIFO structure like a queue gives you Breadth First Search instead, but why?

Comment: Why? What is depth first search and what is breadth first search? If you can answer this, you can answer your own question. Preferably code it and you will know.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you first understand what a stack (FIFO) and queue (LIFO) data structure is. I'm sure you'll be able to reason the rest from there.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIA8HEEUxZI

A short video to get you started.